# Using Selenium IDE to Identify and manipulate a div/input/span combination

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, selenium-ide

The following HTML is part of a facebook event creation dialog. I am trying to manipulate the hour field to be the value 9, and have tried many different combinations, building on advice from others here at StackExchange. This one has got me:

```
<div class="_4nxi" dir="ltr">
<div class="_4nx7 _4nww _5pw0">
<div class="_4nwx">
  <label style="background-color: transparent;" class="_4nx3 _5pw6" for="js_9" aria-hidden="true">7</label>
  <input style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" id="js_9" class="_4nx5" aria-label="hours" aria-valuetext="7" role="spinbutton">
</div>
</div><span class="_4nxh _5pwa" aria-hidden="true">:</span>
<div class="_4nxe _4nww _5pw0">
<div class="_4nwx">
  <label class="_4nx3 _5pw6" for="js_a" aria-hidden="true">30</label>
  <input id="js_a" class="_4nx5" aria-label="minutes" aria-valuetext="30" role="spinbutton">
</div>
</div>
<div class="_4nxa _4nww _5pw0">
<div class="_4nwx">
  <label class="_4nx3 _5pw6" for="js_b" aria-hidden="true">AM</label>
  <input id="js_b" class="_4nx5" aria-label="meridiem" aria-valuetext="AM" role="spinbutton">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't think the input (id=js_9) is the field to manipulate, it seems to be used for other purposes, ie as a 'spinbutton'. I have tried it though.
The Id of the outer div changes dynamically as the value is clicked, so I try to avoid using it (and have not included it above).

I attempted to use `type` and `sendKeys` and `typeKeys` but I think that a combination of not having the correct Command and various divs/inputs and spans means I am missing the solution. Recording the actions shows no interaction. Suggestions appreciated.

I have tried the following:

```
typeKeys|//div[@class='_4nx7 _4nww _5pw0 _5pw1']|9
click|//div[@class='_4nx7 _4nww _5pw0 _5pw1']
```

and

```
typeKeys|//label[@class='_4nx3 _5pw6']|9
click|//label[@class='_4nx3 _5pw6']
```

and

```
typeKeys|id=js_9|9
click|id=js_9
```

and

```
sendKeys|//div[@class='_4nwx']|9
```

Comment: Also do you really need to use Selenium IDE for facebook event creation? Why are you doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an usual input field behind that label. So you can:

```
sendKeys | //input[@class='_4nx5'] | 9
```

Useful cheat - never use id on facebook. It's not stable.

Comment: This does work, though it was also unstable as that style was used by other fields, namely another hour field on the same page! So I used this: `//th[text()="Start"]/../td/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[input/@aria-label='hours']/input/` This looks at the inner HTML and focuses on the specific hour by looking at the row name. I agree @Antesser ids are unstable. I am doing it to create some prototypes and customer use cases for API projects.